# Where is the link to phpmyadmin in Google Compute Engine?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, google-compute-engine

I set up a LAMP instance in Google Compute Engine approx 45 days ago, and it came with phpMyAdmin already set up and accessible via a button in the console (in Compute Engine -> VM instances -> instance-name -> phpMyAdmin).

The button is now gone, and I can't find any documentation regarding the change. I can still access it via the browser at my-ip/phpmyadmin.

Just wondering if there was some recent change I was unaware of. I can update phpmyadmin manually but it appears that GCE no longer "officially" supports it.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you deployed your LAMP stack via deployment manager. https://console.cloud.google.com/deployments/

If so, you should be able to access your deployment and all the relative details over there including login link for phpmyadmin.

As far as support from Google is concerned, since you have already deployed your instance, even if they remove it from their deployments, it will never affect what you have deployed. Moreover I just deployed a new instance and I can see that phpmyadmin is as an option (not sure if it always was). But even after adding it to my deployment, no extra instance for phpmyadmin was created. It is in the same instance as my rest of stack.

Since you are able to access it via your URL, there's nothing be worried about, and there are no changes on GCP side either. If anything, phpmyadmin is now optional.